# Egypt Pefsu problem

Tags: math-history

Looking at the pefsu problem of the Moscow Mathematical Papyrus [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow_Mathematical_Papyrus#Pefsu_problems) I don't understand why the algorithm takes 1/2 of the calculated grain measure to produce beer. Why aren't the 5 heqats multiplied by 4 to get 20 quantities of beer which would be a better deal in exchange?

The problem transcribed:

1. Example of calculating $100$ loaves of bread of pefsu $20$
2. If someone says to you: "You have $100$ loaves of bread of pefsu $20$
3. to be exchanged for beer of pefsu $4$
4. like $1/2$ $1/4$ malt-date beer"
5. First calculate the grain required for the $100$ loaves of the bread of pefsu $20$
6. The result is $5$ heqat. Then reckon what you need for a des-jug of beer like the beer called $1/2$ $1/4$ malt-date beer
7. The result is $1/2$ of the heqat measure needed for des-jug of beer made from Upper-Egyptian grain.
8. Calculate $1/2$ of $5$ heqat, the result will be $2$ $1/2$
9. Take this $2$ $1/2$ four times
10. The result is $10$. Then you say to him:
11. "Behold! The beer quantity is found to be correct."

Comment: Look up the reference given at the bottom of the problem.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer I looked at it and there is no information regarding my problem. It's just written out like on wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is that "a des-jug of beer like the beer called 1/2 1/4 malt-date beer" just requires half the grain than beer made from Upper-Egyptian grain. I know basically nothing about making beer, but could be because the grain required is more valuable, or somehow the process to make 1/2 1/4 malt-date beer uses other ingredients or something.

Comment: But still, if it requires less grain wouldn't you rather get 20 beers in exchange rather than 10? If it requires half as much where is the other $2\frac{1}{2}$ of grain left?